# Sentry cant connect to Keycloak with organization Certificate - SSL problem

Tags: ssl, keycloak, sentry

This Error: Could not verify SSL certificate. Ensure that your IdP instance has a valid SSL certificate that is linked to a trusted root certificate.

I try to install certs in sentry-web and sentry-worker pods. After that i can curl keycloak from pod without error. But cant connect from Sentry Web console

How to add corporative certs to Sentry. To add Keyckloak realms. And use Keykloak autorizaation